# How to run enum functions with conditions of another enumerable?

Tags: enums, elixir

Finding it difficult to put my problem into words..

I have a function to sort an enumerable with specific conditions and i have another enumerable specified with `Enum.take(x, -1)`

```
Enum.map(list, fn x -> Enum.take(x, 1) end)
|> Enum.map(fn x -> Enum.join(x) end)
|> Enum.sort(&(byte_size(&1) > byte_size(&2)))
|> Enum.with_index
```

What i want to do is apply this function to the second enumerable but with the conditions of the first, such that the items match up with the original position of the first, sort of like this:

```
iex(1)> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
iex(2)> y = [:a,:b,:c,:d,:e] 
[:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]

...
# arbitrary code to sort x such that x = [5,4,3,2,1]
# and y is sorted with the same conditions applied to x such that..
...

iex(4)> y = [:e,:d,:c,:b,:a]
[:e, :d, :c, :b, :a]
```

How might i achieve this? What sort of workaround can i use or are there any specific language features that can do what i need?

I hope my problem makes sense and thank you for reading :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you're trying to do is a list of one property sorted by another property. I think you could do something like this:

```
xs = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
ys = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]

Enum.zip(xs, ys) # Produces a list of pairs like {5, :a}, etc.
|> Enum.sort_by(fn {x, _y} -> x end)
|> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 1))
# => [:e, :d, :c, :b, :a]
```

So basically pack your data into pairs, sort the pairs and then unpack the second element.

You actually can just `Enum.sort()` instead of the `sort_by`, because the default order for tuples is to compare by first element, then the second if first is equal, etc., but this is maybe more explicit.

Comment: thank you! yes this is exactly what i wanted

Comment: how might I implement the original sort function in my code with two elements?
struggling with the syntax of sort_by/sort with `fn {x, _} ->`

Comment: Use `|> Enum.sort_by(fn {x, _y} -> byte_size(x) end)` or like.